# Sync tags in slave repos using git subtree

Tags: git, repository, git-subtree, packagist, subtree

I have a repository on github that is made up by different modules. I prefer to have all these modules under the same repository (it's easier to work, for me), however I also need to be able to mantain a "separate copy" of these modules, because I need to submit them separately on packagist.

After a bit of research on git subtree I found this tool [splitsh-lite](https://www.github.com/splitsh/lite), that was able to solve my problem.

Anyway, versioning on packagist is achieved with tags. What I would like to do is "pushing" the tag along with the commit when issuing a command like `git subtree push -P lib/ lib_remote master`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I wrote a [simple shell script](https://gist.github.com/sneppy/94a3cf95b7cebd9602e368c73e8e3a38) to do this.

You can find a more complex script [here](https://bitbucket.org/ua_drupal/uaqs_repository_tools/src/7.x-1.x/tagsplits.sh?fileviewer=file-view-default)